# recursive array change key case not satisfying uppercase

Tags: php, phpunit

I have created a custom function to handle changing the array key case recursively.

Here is the static constants in the class:

```
/**
 * KEY_CASE_UPPER is used with
 * array_change_key_case and is used to convert array
 * keys to upper case.
 */
const KEY_CASE_UPPER = 1;

/**
 * KEY_CASE_LOWER is used with
 * array_change_key_case and is used to convert array
 * keys to lower case.
 */
const KEY_CASE_LOWER = 0;
```

And here is the method:

```
public static function arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive(array $array,int $case=null):array
{
    $ret=[];
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            if($case===static::KEY_CASE_LOWER){
                if(is_string($k)){
                   $ret[strtolower($k)]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
                } else {
                   $ret[$k]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
                }
            } else {
                if(is_string($k)){
                    $ret[strtoupper($k)]=$v;
                } else {
                    $ret[$k]=$v;
                }
            }
        } elseif(is_string($k)) {
            if($case===static::KEY_CASE_LOWER){
                $ret[strtolower($k)]=$v;
            } else {
                $ret[strtoupper($k)]=$v;
            }
        } else {
            $ret[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**For some reason, it works fine with `lowercase` but does not work for `uppercase`**

Here are the unit tests:

```
public function testArrayChangeKeyCaseRecursiveSatisfiesLowerCase()
{
    $data=[
      0=>['FOO'=>0,'BAR'=>1,'BAZ'=>2],
      1=>['SUM'=>0,'WORLD'=>1,'DAT'=>2],
      2=>['ADD'=>0,'DIVIDE'=>1,'MULTIPLY'=>2]
    ];
    $expected=[
        0=>['foo'=>0,'bar'=>1,'baz'=>2],
        1=>['sum'=>0,'world'=>1,'dat'=>2],
        2=>['add'=>0,'divide'=>1,'multiply'=>2]
    ];
    $actual = PhpArray::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($data,PhpArray::KEY_CASE_LOWER);
    $this->assertEquals($expected,$actual);
}

public function testArrayChangeKeyCaseRecursiveSatisfiesUpperCase()
{
    $data=[
        0=>['foo'=>0,'bar'=>1,'baz'=>2],
        1=>['sum'=>0,'world'=>1,'dat'=>2],
        2=>['add'=>0,'divide'=>1,'multiply'=>2]
    ];
    $expected=[
        0=>['FOO'=>0,'BAR'=>1,'BAZ'=>2],
        1=>['SUM'=>0,'WORLD'=>1,'DAT'=>2],
        2=>['ADD'=>0,'DIVIDE'=>1,'MULTIPLY'=>2]
    ];
    $actual = PhpArray::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($data,PhpArray::KEY_CASE_UPPER);
    $this->assertEquals($expected,$actual);
}
```

I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are casting to lowercase, you process recursively.
However, when you casting to uppercase, you just cast keys of the first layer.

```
        if($case===static::KEY_CASE_LOWER){
            if(is_string($k)){
               $ret[strtolower($k)]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
            } else {
               $ret[$k]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
            }
        } else {
            if(is_string($k)){
                $ret[strtoupper($k)]=$v;
            } else {
                $ret[$k]=$v;
            }
        }
```

You should cast to uppercase recursively as well.

```
            if ($case===static::KEY_CASE_LOWER) {
                if (is_string($k)) {
                    $ret[strtolower($k)]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v, $case);
                } else {
                    $ret[$k]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v, $case);
                }
            } else {
                if (is_string($k)) {
                    $ret[strtoupper($k)]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v, $case);
                } else {
                    $ret[$k]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v, $case);
                }
            }
```

It passes the unit test.

Answer (score 2):

I think your function can be significantly simplified:

```
public static function arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive(array $array, int $case = null): array
{
    $mutated = [];
    $mutator = $case === self::KEY_CASE_LOWER ? 'strtolower' : 'strtoupper';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        // Mutate string keys
        if (is_string($key)) $key = $mutator($key);

        // Mutate array values
        if (is_array($value)) $value = self::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($value, $case);

        $mutated[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $mutated;
}
```

Comment: Need to swap `$this->arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive` to `self::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive`

Comment: Cheers. I forgot it was a `static` function.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
public static function arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive(array $array,int $case=null):array
{

    $ret=[];
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        if(is_array($v))
        {
            if($case === static::KEY_CASE_LOWER)
            {
                if(is_string($k)){
                   $ret[strtolower($k)]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
                } else {
                   $ret[$k]=static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
                }
            } else { // uppercase
                if(is_string($k))
                {
                    $ret[strtoupper($k)] = static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
                } else {
                    $ret[$k] = static::arrayChangeKeyCaseRecursive($v,$case);
                }
            }
        } elseif(is_string($k)) {
            if($case === static::KEY_CASE_LOWER)
            {
                $ret[strtolower($k)] = $v;
            } else { // uppercase
                $ret[strtoupper($k)] = $v;
            }
        } else {
            $ret[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```